# Save Post Data from External Server To Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to save information posted to a callback URL to a Laravel database. I have created a controller and a route in the api.php file but the posted information is not being saved. When I create a PHP file in the public folder, the info is being saved but I want it to go through a controller. Kindly let me know what I need to do to save the info.

Route: `Route::post('/receivesms', 'MessageController@stk');`

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function stk(Request $req){

        $message = new Message();
        $message->sender = $req->input('from');
        $message->recipient = $req->input('to');
        $message->message = $req->input('message');
        $message->date_sent = $req->input('date');
        $message->message_id = $req->input('id');
        $message->link_id = $req->input('linkId');
        $message->save();

        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

The posted info is as explained [here](http://docs.africastalking.com/sms/callback). with the posted data being;

```
 $from = $_POST['from'];
 $to = $_POST['to'];
 $text = $_POST['text'];
 $date = $_POST['date'];
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $linkId = $_POST['linkId'];
```

Comment: can you describe more what you are trying to achive

Comment: To simplify the question, given the Post data, how do I save it in a Laravel database.

Comment: you are already doing it with `stk` function

Comment: This is not working. Is this how data from outside Laravel is handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put routes in `api.php` file `api` is prefixed in the route automatically refer this link [Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#basic-routing)

so if your laravel aplication is running on `https://example.com` then `Route::post('/receivesms', 'MessageController@stk');` will translate to `https://example.com/api/receivesms`

So make sure your callback your is containing `api` prefix, It should work.

All the Best

K

Comment: That was it. I added the prefix and it's now working perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Great, You may except this as the answer, would would help other quickly recognize that this helped you.